# Problems connecting to data folder using sage sdo18.(ForwardCallToInvokeMember)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, unc, sage-erp

I'm developing an automatic invoicing system using c#.net v4.0 and Sage's SDO. The Application works fine on my local machine both in a development environment and on iis 7. I am now trying to implement it on a live server and I am getting the following error:

> SAGE EXCEPTION:Not connected to Data Source - Connect or Logon failed .
>
> Error Code:sdoNotConnected
>
> StackTrace: at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData) at SageDataObject180.IWorkSpace.CreateObject(String Name) at RestrictedPages_ViewReport.GenerateInvoice(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\IE Support Manager Integration\RestrictedPages\ViewReport.aspx.cs:line 386

The iis7 process is running on a 32 bit process. The folder is hosted on a machine on the network but not on the machine that the web application is installed on. I can read and write to this folder from the web application so I doubt its a permissions problem.

I've been tearing my hair out with this problem for 2 days now so any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Did you even find a solution for this?

Comment: @elector Did you have a similar problem to this and find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the actual code where the error is happening? I am guessing its permissions or a variable that needs changing.